# ECHO is off appended to text file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have in a batch file the following code:

```
rem capture the date/time(right down to the second) and then assign it to a variable
set yy=%date:~-4%
set dd=%date:~-7,2%
set mm=%date:~-10,2%
set newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy%_%Time:~0,8%
set newdate=%newdate::=%
set foldername=svetlana_backup_%newdate%
set foldername=%foldername: =%

set destination=R:\Backup

if exist %destination% (
    rem do stuff if destination exists.
) else (
    call:GenerateErrorLog "%destination% not found."
)


:GenerateErrorLog
echo %~1 >> error_log_%foldername%.txt
goto:eof
```

It generates the following text file:

```
R:\Backup not found. 
ECHO is off.
```

Why does it print ECHO is off, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Put a `GOTO :EOF` after the last parentheses of the `IF ELSE` clause.  But I am not seeing any reason why you need to CALL to a label just to echo that to your log file.  Why not put the echo in the `ELSE` clause?

Comment: @Squashman - the batch file is a lot bigger than what I posted here. I took out the code that was irrelevant and posted it. There are a lot of else clauses that echo errors, so I decided to create a function.

Comment: So you understand that all your functions should be at the end of your batch file and that you should have a `GOTO :EOF` or `EXIT /B` as the line before all your functions so that it exits the batch file without trying to execute all your functions again?

Comment: @Squashman - Sure do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the value `%~1` is empty, so `echo` reports its status.

To fix: Use `echo(` in place of `echo[Space]` - the `(` plays no part in parenthesis-counting for nested routines, but has been found to suppress the `echo` report for an empty argument {quirk}

Comment: What a quirk! Just favorited!

Comment: Well technically that is the cause but what really should be used is a `GOTO :EOF` after the `IF..ELSE` clause so that is does not execute the `echo %1` twice.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Squashman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694) already pointed out by some [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864215/echo-is-off-appended-to-text-file#comment67016613_39864215), you need to prevent from executing the subroutine `: GenerateErrorLog` unintentionally after the main section of your script has finished.

The technical cause of the `ECHO is off.` message is already explained in [@Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864262).

But why is `%~1` empty, although the calling command line `call:GenerateErrorLog "%destination% not found."` certainly provides a non-empty argument? This is because the way batch files are handled: there are no real functions and subroutines like in other (true) programming languages; a batch file is designed to execute the entire file line by line from top to bottom; there are only very few ways to modify the execution flow or directon (`if`, `for`, `goto`, `call`, `&&`, `||`); to not execute certain portions of code you need to control that explicitly. So in your code, after the `if exist` clause execution continues with the next lines, which constitute the subroutine, so this is executed as it was part of the main section. Therefore, `%~1` is no longer considered as the first argument of the subroutine but of the entire batch script; since you do not supply such, `%~1` expands to an empty string.

You can simply prove that if you call your batch file -- let us call it `script.bat` -- from a command prompt window (point to directory containing the script), by delivering an argument:

```dos
script.bat ##TEST##
```

This will result in the following log entry (instead of `ECHO is off.`):

> ```dos
> ##TEST##
> ```

So once again: append `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` to the end of the main section of your batch script:

```dos
:: /* initial code... */
if exist %destination% (
    rem do stuff if destination exists.
) else (
    call:GenerateErrorLog "%destination% not found."
)
goto :EOF

:GenerateErrorLog
:: /* remaining code... */
```